# Prove $((P \cup Q) \cap (P \to R) \cap (Q \to R)) \to R $ is a Tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$[(P \cup Q) \cap (P \rightarrow R) \cap (\neg Q \cup R)] \rightarrow R $ Logical Equivalences.

$[(P \cup Q) \cap (\neg P \cup R) \cap (\neg Q \cup R)] \rightarrow R$ Logical Equivalences.

$\neg[(P \cup Q) \cap (\neg P \cup R) \cap (\neg Q \cup R)] \cup R$ Logical Equivalences.

$[\neg(P \cup Q) \cup \neg (\neg P \cup R) \cup \neg (\neg Q \cup R)] \cup R$ De Morgan’s Laws.

$(\neg P \cap \neg Q) \cup (P \cap \neg R) \cup (Q \cap \neg R) \cup R$ De Morgan’s Laws.

I'm thinking I can use the distributive property here, but I don't know how I would set that up.

$(\neg P \cup P) \cap (\neg P \cup ¬R) \cap (\neg Q \cup P) \cap (\neg Q \cup \neg R)$   $\leftarrow$ That is as far as I have gotten as I am unsure if I continue to distribute the letters throughout the entire thing or not like this instead:

$(\neg P \cup P \cup Q \cup R) \cap (\neg P \cup \neg R \cup \neg R \cup R) \cap (\neg Q \cup P \cup Q \cup R) \cap (\neg Q \cup \neg R \cup \neg R \cup R).$

Now that I look at it, I think the second way looks correct, but I'm still unsure.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: What rules are you allowed?

Comment: Identity Laws, domination, idempotent, double negation, commutative, associative, distributive, De Morgan's, Absorption, and Negation laws.  

For logical Equivalences, we're only allowed to use
 P->Q = ~P v Q and P <-> Q = (P -> Q) ^ (Q-> P)

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I thought for distributive, you had to distribute the letter throughout all of it.  Why is it ((P ^ (P ->R))v(Q ^(Q-> R)))->R and not ((P ^ (P ->R) ^ (Q-> R)) v (Q ^ (P -> R) ^ (Q-> R))->R?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
use modus ponendo ponens:

$P\land (P\implies Q)\implies Q$.

And the distributive rules.

Answer (score 1):

$[\neg (P \cup Q) \cup \neg(\neg P \cup R) \cup \neg(\neg Q \cup R)] \cup R.$ (line 4 of your derivation)

$[\neg (P \cup Q) \cup (P \cap \neg R) \cup (Q \cap \neg R)] \cup R.$

$\{\neg (P \cup Q) \cup [(P \cup Q) \cap \neg R]\} \cup R.$

$\neg (P \cup Q) \cup \{ [(P \cup Q) \cap \neg R] \cup R\}.$

$\neg (P \cup Q) \cup \{[(P \cup Q) \cup R] \cap (\neg R \cup R)\}.$

$\neg (P \cup Q) \cup \{[(P \cup Q) \cup R] \cap \textbf{T}\}.$

$\neg (P \cup Q) \cup [(P \cup Q) \cup R].$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is true, then $\to$ is true. ($A\to T=T$), so $R$ must be false for the tautology to fail.

So we need to prove that if $R=F$ then the LHS is false.

As $A\to F=\lnot A$, from $(P\to R)\cap (Q\to R)$ we get $(P\to F)\cap (Q\to F)=\lnot P\cap\lnot Q=\lnot(P\lor Q)$

So the LHS becomes $(P\lor Q)\land\lnot(P\lor Q)=F$.

Comment: Now I understand your comment. :-) Concise answer. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Truth tables are often a convenient alternative. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc}
((&P& \cup& Q&) \cap ((&P& \to &R&) &\cap& (&Q& \to& R&))) &\to& R\\
\hline
&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&\color{blue}{1}&1\\
&1&1&1&0&1&0&0&&0&&1&0&0&&\color{blue}{1}&0\\
&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&&\color{blue}{1}&1\\
&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&&0&&0&1&0&&\color{blue}{1}&0\\
&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&\color{blue}{1}&1\\
&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&&0&&1&0&0&&\color{blue}{1}&0\\
&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&&\color{blue}{1}&1\\
&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&0&&\color{blue}{1}&0\\
\hline
&1& 4& 2&6 &1& 4 &3& &5& &2& 4& 3& &7& 3\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

The bottom row in the table indicates the order of evaluation.